# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.cloudant.spark. in IBM BigInsights cluster

Tags: ibm-cloud, apache-spark-sql, cloudant, biginsights

I have created an IBM BigInsights service instance with hadoop cluster of 5 nodes (including Apache Spark). I trying to use SparkR to connect a Cloudant Database, get some data, and do some processing.

I have launched a SparkR shell(terminal) and ran the following code:

```
sparkR.stop()
# Creating SparkConext and connecting to Cloudant DB
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkEnv = list("cloudant.host"="<<cloudant-host-name>>","<<><<cloudant-user-name>>>","cloudant.password"="<<cloudant-password>>", "jsonstore.rdd.schemaSampleSize"="-1"))

# Database to be connected to extract the data
database <- "testdata"
# Creating Spark SQL Context
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
# Creating DataFrame for the "testdata" Cloudant DB
testDataDF <- read.df(sqlContext, database, header='true', source = "com.cloudant.spark",inferSchema='true')
```

I am getting the following error messages:

```
16/08/05 19:00:27 ERROR RBackendHandler: loadDF on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.cloudant.spark. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.loadDF(SQLUtils.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils.loadDF(SQLUtils.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBacke
```

How do you install the spark-cloudant connector in IBM BigInsights and resolve the issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the packages to sparkR.init:

```
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkPackages="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.0.3")
```

See here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sparkr.html#from-data-sources

The spark cloudant package is here:

https://spark-packages.org/package/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant

For a 4.2 cluster, I think you need:

```
cloudant-labs:spark-cloudant:1.6.4-s_2.10
```